# Object is modified but the array is not

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have an array of objects that are displayed in view and want to update an object in the array using the results of http get call.

the object (item) is updated but it seems when i debug it that this change in the object is not present in the array (this.myArray) and therefor nothing is changed in the view.

**component.ts**

```
myFunction() {
        this.myArray.forEach(item => {
                this._appSvc.modifyObject(item).subscribe(result => {
                    item = result;
                });
        });
    }
```

**appSvs.ts**

```
modifyObject(item): Observable<IItem>{
        return this._http.get(url).map(response => <IItem> response.json());
    }
```

**component.html**

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of myArray | orderBy:{property: sortingAttribute, direction: direction}">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="select-{{item.id}}"
                   id="select-{{item.id}}"
                   [checked]="item.selected"
                   (change)="selectItem(item.id)"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <span>{{item.code}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How do you bind the array with your view ? Do you youse somethinng like ngOnChanges ?

Comment: @Mium check the edited version! i use (change) directive but for an object (i.e. an element of the array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your base array according to the index and the new item you get from your service.

```
myFunction() {
        this.myArray.forEach((item,index) => {
                this._appSvc.modifyObject(item).subscribe(result => {
                    this.myArray[index] = result;
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: You right, I didnt realize that he didnt use Observables. I edit with the right answer.